# Integrate WordPress into existing php site using "the loop"

Tags: wordpress

I'm trying to get WordPress to power a blog on an existing php site. I just want to have a directory www.mysite.com/blog and have wordpress running the pages in that directory, using the same look and feel as the rest of the site.

I'm using the method described in this article :
http://codex.wordpress.org/Integrating_WordPress_with_Your_Website

I already have everything up and running, but I can't find the appropriate php files to edit the css in the wordpress template. I don't know wordpress at all, so I can't trace back to the correct file without knowing the wordpress syntax.

I'm using the WordPress TwentyTwelve them. Can somebody tell me which php and css files control the right hand menu layout?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find the relevant files here:

http://yourdomain.com/wp-content/themes/twentytwelve/

The main stylesheet is style.css and the php files are all in there as well to edit to your liking.

NB. if you included the wordpress folder, it will be .../wordpress/wp-content/ etc.

Comment: I know where the php and css files are. I can't find which one contains the needed code.

Comment: Please can I see a link to assist with that.

Comment: All the files are in the directory you posted.
Here is the code that displays wordpress data:

<code><?php if ( ! dynamic_sidebar( 'sidebar-1' ) ) : ?>
    <aside id="archives" class="widget">
     <h3 class="widget-title"><?php _e( 'Archives', 'twentyeleven' ); ?></h3>
     <ul>
      <?php wp_get_archives( array( 'type' => 'monthly' ) ); ?>
     </ul>
    </aside>
   <?php endif; // end sidebar widget area ?></code>

Comment: Is that what you are asking for??

Comment: for the css yes. That is the css I need. But the sidebar.php is just calling something else. I think that the code in there is the code I pasted above. I need the php file that controls what is displayed so I can change the order of the items on the sidebar and delete some.

Comment: So you added the widgets in the Wordpress backend? Under Appearance - Widgets... You can drag and drop/remove the widgets that's currently displayed. Alternatively you can find the functions for the sidebar in functions.php...

Comment: I need the function :
    dynamic_sidebar( 'sidebar-1' )

i can't find it

Comment: Like I said above, the functions are in functions.php for the different sidebars.. Look on line 204. Basically my answer is correct, the style.css holds the css and you weren't specific about what you wanted from the sidebar. Please use a multi file search text editor like Text Wrangler to search multiple files.

Comment: I guess it is wordpress and not php, because I don't know what any of that stuff is.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/32274/discussion-between-ascii-dude-and-msbodetti)